# [ERROR][logstash.config.sourceloader] No configuration found in the configured sources

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, elk

I am installing Logstash locally on windows 10, to check whether logstash is working or not i have create logstash-simple.conf file which is located in logstash folder. But when running the command:
bin/logstash -f logstash-simple.conf
I am not able to type on cmd after : Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
even if i type it is not shownup and logstash is exited
I am get the following errors:
cmd
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuNnu.png)

logstash-simple.config
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDscU.png)

Comment: Make sure to paste the actual error as text and not as image. Among other reasons, it means those that make use of assistive technologies are unable to read them.

Answer (score 3):

As the error suggests, The logstash isnt able to find your file logstash-simple.conf
Please type the whole absolute path in your command:

> logstash -f absolute/path/to/your/conf/file/here